# @nuxt/http won't send cookies to the API during SSR

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Any idea why `@nuxt/http` doesn't send cookies during SSR to a remote API.

I tried `v0.5` now testing with `v0.3.9`. My setup is as follows:

- local dev domain : `http://dev.example.com`
- remote api domain: `https://example.com:8080`

Cookies are applied to `'.site.com'` so that they are visible on both domains. Client side all is working fine. But seems `@nuxt/http` doesn't proxy cookies or all the headers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in `nuxt.config.js` `target` option must be `server` for the `@nuxt/http` module to proxy the cookies along with all the rest headers.

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
    target: 'server',
}
```